# When will this Recurrence Relation repeat

Tags: math, modulo, recurrence

I have this recurrence formula:

```
   P(n) = ( P(n-1) + 2^(n/2) ) % (X)
   s.t. P(1) = 2;
```

where n/2 is computer integer division i.e. floor of x/2

Since i am taking mod X, this relation should repeat at least with in X outputs.

but it can start repeating before that.

How to find this value?

Comment: Because of taking `mod`, the cycle is of length _at most_ `X`, and of course may be shorter (if, say, P(1) happens to equal P(2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needn't repeat within `x` terms, consider `x = 3`:

```
P(1)  = 2
P(2)  = (P(1)  + 2^(2/2))  % 3 = 4 % 3        = 1
P(3)  = (P(2)  + 2^(3/2))  % 3 = (1 + 2) % 3  = 0
P(4)  = (P(3)  + 2^(4/2))  % 3 = 4 % 3        = 1
P(5)  = (P(4)  + 2^(5/2))  % 3 = (1 + 4) % 3  = 2
P(6)  = (P(5)  + 2^(6/2))  % 3 = (2 + 8) % 3  = 1
P(7)  = (P(6)  + 2^(7/2))  % 3 = (1 + 8) % 3  = 0
P(8)  = (P(7)  + 2^(8/2))  % 3 = 16 % 3       = 1
P(9)  = (P(8)  + 2^(9/2))  % 3 = (1 + 16) % 3 = 2
P(10) = (P(9)  + 2^(10/2)) % 3 = (2 + 32) % 3 = 1
P(11) = (P(10) + 2^(11/2)) % 3 = (1 + 32) % 3 = 0
P(12) = (P(11) + 2^(12/2)) % 3 = (0 + 64) % 3 = 1
```

and you see that the period is 4.

Generally (suppose `X` is odd, it's a bit more involved for even `X`), let `k` be the period of 2 modulo `X`, i.e. `k > 0`, `2^k % X = 1`, and `k` is minimal with these properties (see below).

Consider all arithmetic modulo `X`. Then

```
           n
P(n) = 2 + ∑ 2^(j/2)
          j=2
```

It is easier to see when we separately consider odd and even `n`:

```
                   m           m
P(2*m+1) = 2 + 2 * ∑ 2^i = 2 * ∑ 2^i = 2*(2^(m+1) - 1) = 2^((n+2)/2) + 2^((n+1)/2) - 2
                  i=1         i=0
```

since each `2^j` appears twice, for `j = 2*i` and `j = 2*i+1`. For even `n = 2*m`, there's one summand `2^m` missing, so

```
P(2*m) = 2^(m+1) + 2^m - 2 = 2^((n+2)/2) + 2^((n+1)/2) - 2
```

and we see that the length of the period is `2*k`, since the changing parts `2^((n+1)/2)` and `2^((n+2)/2)` have that period. The period immediately begins, there is no pre-period part (there can be a pre-period for even `X`).

Now `k <= φ(X)` by [Euler's generalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_theorem) of Fermat's theorem, so the period is at most `2 * φ(X)`.
(φ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), i.e. `φ(n)` is the number of integers `1 <= k <= n` with `gcd(n,k) = 1`.)

---

What makes it possible that the period is longer than `X` is that `P(n+1)` is not completely determined by `P(n)`, the value of `n` also plays a role in determining `P(n+1)`, in this case the dependence is simple, each power of 2 being used twice in succession doubles the period of the pure powers of 2.

Consider the sequence `a[k] = (2^k) % X` for odd `X > 1`. It has the simple recurrence

```
a[0] = 1
a[k+1] = (2 * a[k]) % X
```

so each value completely determines the next, thus the entire following part of the sequence. (Since `X` is assumed odd, it also determines the previous value [if `k > 0`] and thus the entire previous part of the sequence. With `H = (X+1)/2`, we have `a[k-1] = (H * a[k]) % X`.)

Hence if the sequence assumes one value twice (and since there are only `X` possible values, that must happen within the first `X+1` values), at indices `i` and `j = i+p > i`, say, the sequence repeats and we have `a[k+p] = a[k]` for all `k >= i`. For odd `X`, we can go back in the sequence, therefore `a[k+p] = a[k]` also holds for `0 <= k < i`. Thus the first value that occurs twice in the sequence is `a[0] = 1`.

Let `p` be the smallest positive integer with `a[p] = 1`. Then `p` is the length of the smallest period of the sequence `a`, and `a[k] = 1` if and only if `k` is a multiple of `p`, thus the set of periods of `a` is the set of multiples of `p`. Euler's theorem says that `a[φ(X)] = 1`, from that we can conclude that `p` is a divisor of `φ(X)`, in particular `p <= φ(X) < X`.

Now back to the original sequence.

```
P(n) = 2 + a[1] + a[1] + a[2] + a[2] + ... + a[n/2]
     = a[0] + a[0] + a[1] + a[1] + a[2] + a[2] + ... + a[n/2]
```

Since each `a[k]` is used twice in succession, it is natural to examine the subsequences for even and odd indices separately,

```
E[m] = P(2*m)
O[m] = P(2*m+1)
```

then the transition from one value to the next is more regular. For the even indices we find

```
E[m+1] = E[m] + a[m] + a[m+1] = E[m] + 3*a[m]
```

and for the odd indices

```
O[m+1] = O[m] + a[m+1] + a[m+1] = O[m] + 2*a[m+1]
```

Now if we ignore the modulus for the moment, both `E` and `O` are geometric sums, so there's an easy closed formula for the terms. They have been given above (in slightly different form),

```
E[m] = 3 * 2^m - 2     = 3 * a[m] - 2
O[m] = 2 * 2^(m+1) - 2 = 2 * a[m+1] - 2 = a[m+2] - 2
```

So we see that `O` has the same (minimal) period as `a`, namely `p`, and `E` also has that period. Unless maybe if `X` is divisible by 3, that is also the minimal (positive) period of `E` (if `X` is divisible by 3, the minimal positive period of `E` could be a proper divisor of `p`, for `X = 3` e.g., `E` is constant).

Thus we see that `2*p` is a period of the sequence `P` obtained by interlacing `E` and `O`.

It remains to be seen that `2*p` is the minimal positive period of `P`. Let `m` be the minimal positive period. Then `m` is a divisor of `2*p`.

Suppose `m` were odd, `m = 2*j+1`. Then

```
P(1) = P(m+1) = P(2*m+1)
P(2) = P(m+2) = P(2*m+2)
```

and consequently

```
P(2) - P(1) = P(m+2) - P(m+1) = P(2*m+2) - P(2*m+1)
```

But `P(2) - P(1) = a[1]` and

```
P(m+2)   - P(m+1)   = a[(m+2)/2]            = a[j+1]
P(2*m+2) - P(2*m+1) = a[(2*m+2)/2] = a[m+1] = a[2*j+2]
```

So we must have `a[1] = a[j+1]`, hence `j` is a period of `a`, and `a[j+1] = a[2*j+2]`, hence `j+1` is a period of `a` too. But that means that 1 is a period of `a`, which implies `X = 1`, a contradiction.

Therefore `m` is even, `m = 2*j`. But then `j` is a period of `O` (and of `E`), thus a multiple of `p`. On the other hand, `m <= 2*p` implies `j <= p`, and the only (positive) multiple of `p` satisfying that inequality is `p` itself, hence `j = p`, `m = 2*p`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I admit my wrong assumption that it would go periodic within X. Can you explain in more detail "the periods of 2^((n+1)/2) - 2" and euler's generalization. it would be great if you give some links or books where i can also learn to derive this period thing.

Comment: I've elaborated a bit, hopefully that helps. You should get some info about the topic from following links on the linked wikipedia page, for more, I can only generally point to introductory texts on Algebra and Number Theory, both treat the topic in varying depth. What appropriate texts could be depends on your mathematical foundation. With less than college/university to build on, it's a hard journey either way, with a few semesters of college or university under your belt, it'd be easier, but you should still see which texts are appropriate yourself.

Comment: Very great explaination. I am doing bachelors in computers. I have a problem in understanding this line "Thus we see that 2*p is a period of the sequence P obtained by interlacing E and O." I am unable to figure out this interlacing word.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI You get `P` by picking one item from `O`, then one from`E`, then the next from `O`, the next from `E`... .  I'm not a native speaker, so "interlacing" may be the wrong word, but I think that's the one commonly used.